# Getting 503 (Service Unavailable) when trying to review an item in the Meta CV Queue

Tags: bug, review-queues

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/9178

As soon as I hit "Close" I get a red popup that says "Unable to load popup - please try again"

Then I see this in the console:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
> (Service Unavailable)
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/ajax-load-realtime/301040 Failed
> to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service
> Unavailable) VM241:59 503 "Service Unavailable" "<html>    <head>
>     <title>Too Many Requests - Stack Exchange</title>   </head>    <body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
>     <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;"> 
>           <h2 >We're sorry...</h2>
>           <p>There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.</p>  
>           <p>To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP address right now.</p>       <p>We'll restore access as
> quickly as possible, so try again soon.</p>  
>           <p>If you believe you have reached this page in error, <a href="mailto:team@stackoverflow.com">contact us</a>.</p> 
>     </div>   </body>  </html> 
> 
> "
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/flags/questions/261983/close/popup?loadedTimestamp=1461685567900&reviewTaskId=9178&_=1461685573459
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
> (Service Unavailable)
```

Refreshing the page shows an error:

> We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP
>   address right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

I have all userscripts disabled and am still seeing this error.  Is something wrong on my end?

Comment: Yes, too much co-workers? Send some of them to lunch and try again.

Comment: I'm the only one in my department who uses SO, let alone meta.

Comment: Do note that you need to wait for at least 90 seconds, IIRC,  before you do the next attempt. You're hitting the HA-proxy throttle rule.

Comment: I couldn't find where I got that number from but I found the blog: http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/08/26/1016491873/

Comment: Thanks @rene, you da real MVP.